# using html form with two </form> and submit buttons?

Tags: php, html

```js
 var el = document.getElementById('btn1');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hidEl = document.getElementById('hidElement');
  hidEl.value = 'Add';
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  form.submit();
});
var el2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
el2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hidEl = document.getElementById('hidElement');
  hidEl.value = 'Print';
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  form.submit();
});
```

```html
<?php
if($_POST["hidElement"]=='Add')
 echo "add";
 else
 echo "Print";
?>
    
    
    <form action="" method="">
   

    <input type="text" name="nasir" >
    <input type="hidden" name="hidElement" id="hidElement" />
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit & Add">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Submit & Print">
  </form>
```

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["yasir"]))
echo "Submit & Print";
else
echo "Submit & Add";
?>
    <form action="" method="">          
        <input type="text" name="nasir" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit & Add">
    </form>

        <input type="hidden" name="yasir">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit & Print">
    </form>
```

There is no second  starting for second form. I want both forms use same , but how PHP will recognize which form button has been pressed. I tried above but in both cases it submiting second yasir hidden input!!! 
There is alot of inputs in first form.

Comment: you must have two `<form>` elements.

Comment: At first submit button should be inside the class and next if your using two submit button each must have unique name

Comment: If you need all elements why can't you add them in one form? Can you tell us the use case so that we can understand requirement better?

Comment: @Tapas actually it php where it matters to me, whether user just want to submit and add another element or he/she just want to submit and print plus it means he/she not interest to add another item in same invoice.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

please try this

```
 <form action="" method="post">          
    <input type="text" name="nasir" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit & Add" name="first_btn">

    <input type="hidden" name="yasir">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit & Print"  name="second_btn">
</form>
```

in php you can check by using this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['first_btn'])){
   /*first form submit*/
}
if(isset($_POST['second_btn'])){
   /*second form submit*/
} 
?>
```

Comment: I tried that but if you are using update chrome then it will not support submit button name :(

Comment: You can check if it works by checking with `var_dump($_POST);` it should work

Answer (score 0):

In that case it's better to use javascript to handle form post. You can add to buttons to same form for add and print and handle click on them using javascript. Something like below:

```
<form action="" method="" id="form">          
    <input type="text" name="nasir" >
    <input type="hidden" name="hidElement" id="hidElement" />
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit & Add">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Submit & Print">
</form>
```

In javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById('btn1');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hidEl = document.getElementById('hidElement');
  hidEl.value = 'Add';
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.submit();
});
var el2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
el2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hidEl = document.getElementById('hidElement');
  hidEl.value = 'Print';
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.submit();
});
```

In Php you can check based on hidElement value.

Comment: Please check  and run the above sinppet code, it gives error and not working.

Comment: I was giving an idea on how to implement not exact code. Anyway I updated the code and it will work now.

Comment: I like your idea but still the code is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

For every  there should be an end  also. Otherwise it will not work
try

```
<form action="" method="post">          
<input type="text" name="nasir" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit & Add" name="btn1">

<input type="hidden" name="yasir">
<input type="submit" value="Submit & Print" name="btn2">
</form>
```